# Instagram API response - array length bizarre

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, jsonp, instagram-api

I'm running into a wall with the Instagram API responses I'm receiving.  I'm just pushing the data objects of each tag call response into my empty results array after checking for duplicates.

The resulting array is acting strangely.  In the console the results array shows the full structure and says the length is 5, as expected.  When results.length is logged, however it shows a length of zero. I created a test array with dummy objects as a comparison to show how it should be behaving.

Screenshot of my console is below.

The odd thing is that results.length seems to function correctly in the for loop checking for duplicates.

```
            var token = 'MY_TOKEN',
                userid = MY_ID,
                num_photos = 33,
                hashtags = ['website', 'engraving', 'weddinginvitations', 'customstationery'],
                results = [],
                test_results = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]; 

            // LOOP THROUGH EACH HASH
            for(i = 0; i < hashtags.length; i++){
                // MAKE AJAX CALL PER HASH
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + hashtags[i] + '/media/recent',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
                    success: function(response){
                        // CHECK EACH IMAGE IN THE RESPONSE DATA AND REMOVE DUPLICATES
                        for( x in response.data ){
                            var exists = false;
                            for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
                                if( results[i].id === response.data[x].id ){
                                    exists = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(exists === false){
                                results.push(response.data[x]);
                            } 
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                }); 
            } 


            console.log(results);
            console.log(results.length);

            console.log(test_results);
            console.log(test_results.length);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The success function is executed asynchronously, and dev tools will evaluate the contents of an object at the time you expand it.

If you look in the screenshot at the array you first logged, you'll see it shows as empty. It's only after you expand it that you see its contents. In between logging it and expanding it, it's had plenty of time for the success function to run and fill it.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense now. Hmm, looks like it might not be possible for me to continue working with the results array outside of the success function then. I was planning on sorting the array by creation date and then outputting them to an unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax calls are async, so you get 0 length since none of the calls are complete. So move the console.log inside the success callback like this:

```
if(exists === false){
    results.push(response.data[x]);
} 
if(i === hashtags.length-1){
   console.log(results);
   console.log(results.length);
}
```